# SQL Transaction Log

Tags: sql-server, log

Is there a tool that allows us to have a log of all transactions executed by the sql server?
I am currently using the data profiler but it causes many crashes to the server.
I need a tool to record all the log and store it on another server, to be able to consult more quickly and legibly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of sql server?

Comment: Have you looked into [Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/sql-server-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) or [Log Shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) features?

Comment: sql 2008 r2, no idea of log shipping

Comment: Why do you need this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: a log table like you see in SQL Server Profiler with all active columns

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to see *all* the queries running on a server.

There are ways to do this, but it will add overhead to your system - potentially a lot of overhead, so much so that it could be disruptive to the applications and workloads trying to use it.

You mentioned that using profiler was causing system instability.  On SQL Server 2008 R2, your main other option is to use an extended events session.  This should in theory be lighter weight, but it will probably still be a bit too much for production use, unless your system is just not very busy.

I don't have a 2008 R2 instance handy, but these are the events I would capture in order to see *everything* on a 2017 instance:

- sqlserver.error_reported
- sqlserver.module_end
- sqlserver.rpc_completed
- sqlserver.sp_statement_completed
- sqlserver.sql_batch_completed
- sqlserver.sql_statement_completed

These come out of the "query detail tracking" template provided in SSMS, the script for which looks like this:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [query_detail_tracking] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.session_id)
    WHERE (([package0].[greater_than_uint64]([sqlserver].[database_id],(4))) AND ([package0].[equal_boolean]([sqlserver].[is_system],(0))))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.module_end(SET collect_statement=(1)
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.session_id)
    WHERE (([package0].[greater_than_uint64]([sqlserver].[database_id],(4))) AND ([package0].[equal_boolean]([sqlserver].[is_system],(0))))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.session_id)
    WHERE (([package0].[greater_than_uint64]([sqlserver].[database_id],(4))) AND ([package0].[equal_boolean]([sqlserver].[is_system],(0))))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sp_statement_completed(SET collect_object_name=(1)
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.query_plan_hash,sqlserver.session_id)
    WHERE (([package0].[greater_than_uint64]([sqlserver].[database_id],(4))) AND ([package0].[equal_boolean]([sqlserver].[is_system],(0))))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.session_id)
    WHERE (([package0].[greater_than_uint64]([sqlserver].[database_id],(4))) AND ([package0].[equal_boolean]([sqlserver].[is_system],(0))))),
ADD EVENT sqlserver.sql_statement_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.client_app_name,sqlserver.database_id,sqlserver.query_hash,sqlserver.query_plan_hash,sqlserver.session_id)
    WHERE (([package0].[greater_than_uint64]([sqlserver].[database_id],(4))) AND ([package0].[equal_boolean]([sqlserver].[is_system],(0)))))
ADD TARGET package0.event_file(SET filename=N'query_detail_tracking')
WITH 
(
    MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,
    EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,
    MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=30 SECONDS,
    MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,
    MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,
    TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON,
    STARTUP_STATE=OFF
)
```

On SQL Server 2016 and up, the "Query Store" feature could help capture most or all of the queries running on your system.  But I imagine you're quite a long ways off from upgrading to that version.

---

FYI "Transaction log" is kind of a loaded term in SQL Server, most people will see that and think you mean [the write-ahead log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) used for point-in-time recoverability

Comment: thank you!!!!! you really help me on this!